# Pycharm: Using Jupyter instead of prompt for debugging

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, jupyter

When debugging a .py file within pycharms debug mode i can interact using a python prompt when hitting a breakpoint. Is there any way to use the current state of pycharm within a jupyter notebook istead of the python prompt?

It would make debugging quite a bit easier since you could reuse code snippets for debugging purposes.

I couldn't find anything about it, but for me it feels like it could be a thing.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the right way to debug in iPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409629/what-is-the-right-way-to-debug-in-ipython-notebook)

Comment: I don’t believe it is a duplicate. IIUC, the user wants to debug the current state of the interpreter of pycharm within Jupyter. Is that correct @SyntaxError?

Comment: @kdq0 exactly! i hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31382405/3923163), the functionality you are looking for does not exist. The key piece here is that you're trying to import an existing python interpreter into a new IPython kernel. However, from the post linked, you can attach a notebook to an existing IPython kernel with a little bit of work.

A possible solution would be for you to switch to using an [IPython interpreter in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562734/how-to-run-a-file-in-ipython-console-as-default-instead-of-terminal), then attach to that exising kernel in a notebook when needed (as described in the section above).