# How to embed Jupyter-notebook inside Python code with access to caller's environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Often when I develop code I want to work inside the environment where that code will run. Typically I do this by invoking an IPython interpreter [which I do by setting PYTHONBREAKPOINT to point to a routine that calls `IPython.terminal.embed.InteractiveShellEmbed()`]. I am thinking that it would be way better to do this from Jupyter, where I would end up with a notebook that I could then use to write the final code. To give an example,

```
class Myobj(object):
    def __init__(self,arg1,arg2):
        self.a1 = arg1
        self.a2 = arg2
    def doSomething(self):
        breakpoint()

test = Myobj(2,3)
test.doSomething()
```

Then when my breakpoint runs I end up in Pdb (or with my extension, IPython) and I can access self.a1, etc.

I have tried starting up a notebook server with the following code:

```
j = 1
t = 'test string'
from notebook.notebookapp import NotebookApp
app = NotebookApp()
app.initialize(["--port", "8888"])
app.start()
```

This sort-of-works in that I get a browser window where I can start a notebook, but the global variables I have previously defined are not carried in to the kernel.

I'd think that what I want to do must be possible. This is Python after all.

Answer (score 1):

#### AN OPTION:

I would think you'd start Jupyter already in your environment and then work from there in conjunction with developing your code via your text editor. That way you'd iterate iterate over testing it with the settings in the notebook kernel, and using the notebook's debugging interactive prompt mode. And then further develop based on that.
You can then further develop in the notebook or related code text or just use the notebook to document associated trials and development.
I've put together code and a notebook that takes advantage of the Jupyter's features and abilities to do something along the lines of what you describe, yet in a different order. The code difference is really just a different route to trigger the interactive ipython shell that [works with Jupyter](https://twitter.com/choldgraf/status/972877872502312962).  Because I condensed it to all one notebook for ease you'll have to overlook the clunkiness to see what I'm trying to illustrate, which can be viewed and run **actively** [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gist/fomightez/1877981842f7cae13021f49ce21a8f5b/HEAD?urlpath=%2Flab%2Ftree%2Fdemo-from-inside.ipynb) via the MyBinder service.
Or [the static form viewed here](https://nbviewer.org/gist/fomightez/1877981842f7cae13021f49ce21a8f5b) or the active form [here after the session spins up](https://mybinder.org/v2/gist/fomightez/1877981842f7cae13021f49ce21a8f5b/HEAD?urlpath=%2Flab%2Ftree%2Fdemo-from-inside.ipynb).

What I put in the `[In]` input prompt when in the interactive mode doesn't show in the static view but can be seen by examining the raw code [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fomightez/1877981842f7cae13021f49ce21a8f5b/raw/a08dc7037e49cdce64cf22d240cba0f1b311930d/demo-from-inside.ipynb). Basically in first it was:

- `j`
- `t`
- `self.a1`
- `exit()`

And then in second:

- `j`
- `t`
- `self.ai`. *TYPO. oops.*
- `self.a1`
- `exit()`

---

---

There is also in Jupyter, the magic `%load` command which would read your code text and then let you run it in the notebook namespace. (You can see magic command `%load` illustrate with images [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/top-8-magic-commands-in-jupyter-notebook-c1582e813560).) However, the two versions become distinct subsequent to that. That is why I prefer `%run -i` for developing usually.

---

---

related abilities: JupyterLab allows you to connect a full IPython console in the namespace of any notebook at any time, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/console-would-not-automatically-run-code-typed-in-notebook-kernel/12512/2?u=fomightez). This window can can be arranged as you wish, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/is-it-possible-to-have-new-printouts-at-top-of-cell/12683/2?u=fomightez).

Plus you can now share kernels between notebooks in JupyterLab, see [here](https://twitter.com/randal_olson/status/1016706997193007106).

---

---

related tech: There is also importnb that allows you to import a notebook. This seems backwards from most of what you want but ot does allow that you can even pass in variables in the command line, which is why I bring it up in regards to your seeking to pass things into notebooks, as mentioned [here](https://pypi.org/project/importnb/0.4.0/):

> "importnb can run notebooks as command line scripts. Any literal variable in the notebook, may be applied as a parameter from the command line."

Mostly though it is sort of the opposite of where your focus seems to be.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time. Alas, most of my effort goes into a GUI application with 200K lines. Duplicating the environment where my code will run inside a newly-started Jupyter session is possible, I guess, but probably not easy. [Hmmm, perhaps if I pickled globals(), locals(),... but that still would not give me access to my app's routines], so I really want to launch Jupyter's kernel from inside my app... I think.

Comment: I see. I figured it was something complex like that. [This old question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31385337/8508004) seems related; however, doesn't offer a path either. I was wondering if you can specify somehow the console attached as the IPython debugger be a kernel that could then possibly be connected to JupyterLab. However, I'm out of my depth in complexity there. I'd suggest maybe asking at [the Jupyter Community Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org)? If you do, link in both places so you and others following in your footsteps can find the entire discussion. Posting ...

Comment: <continued> there after no luck here helped in [this case](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-write-a-class-which-naturally-produce-a-latex-output-in-jupyter-notebook/17437?u=fomightez). It may get more knowledgeable eyes on it in a much more focused way there. **Also if you post at Discourse be sure to include the complexity if a very large package specifying a UI running in Python so that the full scope is evident.**

Comment: Excellent. Re-posted as https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/start-a-jupyter-notebook-server-inside-a-routine-with-access-to-environment-of-parent/17473