# Use an already running kernel in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-kernel

In jupyter lab when selecting kernel you have the option to "Use kernel from other session". The same functionality does not exist for jupyter notebook and I could not find any tool to achieve this.

I also looked at the jupyter REST API to see if this is possible to manually specify a kernel for the session. The most relevant section I found is [Patch /api/sessions/{session}](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developers/rest-api.html#patch--api-sessions-session) which seems to just allow changing the 'name' of the session.

Is there any way to share the kernel between multiple sessions in jupyter notebook?

Comment: Have you seen this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31385337/8508004)? By the way, the underlying teach components of the next version of what is considered Jupyter notebook now will be based on JupyterLab, see [here](https://jupyter.org/enhancement-proposals/79-notebook-v7/notebook-v7.html). That may open up more possibilities than the current classic Jupyter notebook interface allows. And abilities such as you are asking for are part of why JupyterLab became the next generation of Jupyter. So it was already made available in the ecosystem.

Comment: @Wayne Thank you for the links! I tried one of the alpha releases of notebook v7 and I can change the kernel in jupyter lab and then use jupyter "notebook" for which the same kernel is used. That seems good! The only drawback is that some of the extensions don't work in this version (even extensions like ToC which are supposed to work are not working for some reason)